# Send Kafka record with header using vertx-kafka-client

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x, kafka-producer-api

I'm using [vertx-kafka-client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-kafka-client/java/) 3.5.1 and I can't find a way to create a `KafkaProducerRecord` with a [header](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/common/header/Headers.html) ?

Is there any way or I have to use the Apache client ?

Comment: Adding link to the issue here: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-kafka-client/issues/99